# How can I add a Notebook background in Glade?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

I want to add a background image to my pages in my notebook. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some examples here, this is the only way I know:
http://erikos.sweettimez.de/2011/11/23/gtk-3-theme-style-your-applications/

Comment: I managed to add a image background to the pages but the image also appear in the tab. How I can remove it from there? My CSS code is GtkNotebook {background-image: url("Notes.png");}